# contact form collects data not post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good. I'm creating a contact form and I have a problem. The thing is that I do not control much of javascript and is where the mistake I can not see ........
I know this in the javascript file that if I take sends me the email correctly. But with the javascript file send email to me, but it's like not pick post data, the form, and send it to me empty. But the thing is that I need this javascript. It is what brings out a little message at the top of the form to report that has been submitted successfully. Without me redirected to a blank page with the information message.
This is the section of the HTML contact form:

```
<div id="contact-section">
    <h3>Contacta con nosotros</h3>
    <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
        </div>                        
        <div class="form-group pull-right social-icons">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Enviar"</input>
        </div>
    </form>        
</div>
```

This sends it to a file called sendmail.php is this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Gracias por contactar con nosotros. Nos pondremos en contacto con usted lo antes posible '
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'jimprogrammer2015@gmail.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

The thing is that the javascript function as I do to teach the Message in the same form that is this:

```
// Contact form validation
    var form = $('.contact-form');
    form.submit(function () {'use strict',
        $this = $(this);
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
            $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        },'json');
        return false;
    });
```

Then, the latter javascript code does me good informing about the Message that was sent, and send it to me, but the email blank.
Without this code sends me While email with all data on the post, but I go to a blank page with the Message. And it stays there ......
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please revise your grammar, I am unable to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much testing (as I said no javascript is not my specialty) I've fixed the problem. In the post method, did not send anything, I lacked the information I send. I sent this:

```js
$.post("sendemail.php, function(data) {

$this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        },'json');
```

He carried the URL and call the function I wanted to do. In my case it was right after calling the URL (sendemail.php), you send the data would be loaded in the URL, and then call the function, like this:

```js
$.post("sendemail.php", {name: document.getElementById("name").value, email: document.getElementById("email").value, message: document.getElementById("message").value}, function(data) {

$this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        },'json');
```

As you see, collect the form values to send. I spent the documentation that has come to me very well.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually posting your data check docs http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

You rewrite your js code like this

```
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function (event) {'use strict',
    event.preventDefault();//preventDefault
    var $this = $(this), data = $this.serialize();//serialize data
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), {data: data}, function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');//add post data as second parameter
});
```

In your php code

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Gracias por contactar con nosotros. Nos pondremos en contacto con usted lo antes posible '
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['data']['name']));//get post data
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['data']['email']));//get post data
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['data']['subject']));//get post data
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['data']['message']));//get post data

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'jimprogrammer2015@gmail.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

Comment: Tell me what follows:
Name: n
Email: n
Subject:n
Message:n

Comment: @nachito777sk can you pls elaborate your comment I don't understand your point

Comment: I'm sorry. The problem is that the email sent contains the following:

Email: n

Subject: n

Message: n

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Contact form validation
    var form = $('.contact-form');
    form.submit(function () {'use strict',
        $this = $(this);
        $.post($(this).attr('action'),{data : $(this).serialize()} , function(data) {
            $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
        },'json');
        return false;
    });
```

Try this snippet, you have to serialize form then send.

Comment: I keep going the same

Comment: please before you assign the vars put this code and post here the result:
var_dump($_POST);die;

Comment: backup your sendmail.php and create a new one with this code <?php var_dump($_POST); ?> and put here the output